# If The Field Is NULL The Number Will Not Appear - USING PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a blank data in mysql, and when I call it that blank data. The Number will Appear... Example

1. Sample Data
2. --Blank--
3. Sample Data

I want to remove the Number 2. so that it will become 1-2..

```
$num = 0;
```

I use $num++ foreach data;

```
$num = 0;

mysql_connect('localhost','root','');

mysql_select_db('dbase');

$SQL = " SELECT * FROM table ";
$query = mysql_query($SQL);

while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))   
{
 $num++;

 echo $num;

 echo $data['Name'] 

}
```

OUTPUT :

```
1. SAMPLE
2.
3. SAMPLE
```

I want to make this

```
1. SAMPLE
2. SAMPLE
```

Comment: You should post your PHP code, then describe what do you want exactly.

Comment: God Bless you @Sнаđошƒаӽ.. If you cant help.. just ignore my question.. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for being so polite. I will delete my last comment. You on the other hand should edit your question, and improve it, so that no one gets angry anymore. ;-) These should help: [ask], creating a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a condition in a WHERE clause on the SQL query so that only the rows you want to display are returned, I'd also recommend you add an ORDER BY clause to your query, so the result is more deterministic. And if you only need one column returned (the `Name` column), then specify the column in the SELECT list, instead of returning *all* columns in the table.

```
SELECT t.Name
    FROM table t
WHERE t.name <> ''
   ORDER BY t.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ***if statement*** to check if the value is empty.

Do this:

```
If($data['Name'] != ''){
   $num++;
   echo $num;
   echo $data['Name'];
}
```

Comment: it works but there's a space between 1 and 2 i think the Blank data is still in there.